# How to host a Reactjs project on multiple subdirectories using react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, web-hosting

I have a React app using React Router that I'm currently working on and hosting at the subdirectory /production/app . I got this working by adding `"homepage": "/production/app"` to my package.json file and `basename='/production/app'` to the BrowserRouter.

The problem is I want to host a qa branch at /qa/app and other subdirectories. Is there a way to do this without having to go in and change my hard coded basename and homepage values?

Comment: You may be able to use `"homepage": "."`. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-the-same-build-from-different-paths You can then probably specify the `basename` prop as an environment variable or similar.

Comment: reading the react docs it looks like making that `"homepage": "."` change in package.json makes all paths relative to index.html. Would I then have to add a Base tag to my index.html with the same path as the basename?